# JNA pointer to unsigned char*

Tags: java, c, jna

I have an array of bytes and I want to pass it to C function using JNA.
However I only found examples which allocated a pointer using new Memory and used write function to copy array data but for me is not acceptable because I have big block of data.

Is there a possibility just to pass my Java array directly to c library ?

I want to do something like this :

```
MyLib lib = Native.loadLibrary("test");
Pointer p = myByteArray; //I want to make it possible
lib.someFunction(p);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Passing a primitive array or a `Pointer` to memory are equivalent operations, i.e. you can map like this:

```
public interface MyLibrary extends Library {
    void someFunction(byte[] input);
    void someFunction(Pointer input);
}
```